# Why does Windsor claim my IEnumerable<T> parameter isn't registered?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a factory that takes in `IEnumerable<IPredicate>` in the constructor. My factory signature looks like this.

```
public ServiceFactory(IEnumerable<IPredicate> predicates)
```

And here is my Windsor registering code.

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel, false));

container.Register(Component
    .For<IServiceFactory>()
    .ImplementedBy<ServiceFactory>());
container.Register(AllTypes.
    FromThisAssembly().
    BasedOn<IPredicate>().
    WithService.AllInterfaces());
container.Register(Component
    .For<IEnumerable<IPredicate>>());
```

Windsor throws an exception when I resolve `IServiceFactory` because it says I haven't registered constructor parameter `predicates`. But as you can see the third component I register is the thing it says I haven't registered.

The exception is:

```
Keys (components with specific keys)
- predicates which was not registered.
```

What am I missing?

The odd thing is that I originally wrote this code in a separate project and imported it into my production project. Is it possible that I have another installer interfering with this?

I'm using Castle Windsor v2.5.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your other project most likely has this thing somewhere:

```
var kernel = container.Kernel;

kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(kernel));
```

because this is the thing that makes Windsor do a `ResolveAll` for the type inside various collection types, including `IEnumerable<T>`.

And then you should remove the `container.Register(Component.For<IEnumerable<IPredicate>>())` thing - that line doesn't really register anything, and that might be the reason why the collection resolver doesn't kick in.

Comment: The first statement in my installer adds `CollectionResolver`. I've tried adding it after I initialize `WindsorContainer` but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: try removing the registration of `IEnumerable<IPredicate>`

Answer (score 2):

After reading my question for the 5346 time it finally clicked. The test project where I initially wrote this code was a simple one project test. However, my production project has several different projects in one solution. The things I was asking Windsor to resolve live in a separate assembly. My installer was telling Windsor to register all types based on `IPredicate` from the current assembly using `FromThisAssembly()`. Obviously, I told Windsor to find things it couldn't find.

The simple fix was to use `FromAssemblyNamed("Your.Assembly.Name")` instead.

So *always* check which assemblies you tell Windsor to check.